# How to slice Pandas data frame by column header value when the column header is a date-time value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file where the column name consists of date-time value.

[image]

As you can see the header value is in date-time format. I have loaded this to Pandas dataframe and the header values are indeed saved as date-time value.

Now if I need to query from Pandas such as, "pick all columns which are greater than May-15" how can I do that?

I am aware that by querying `df[df.columns[3:]]` I can achieve this. But I really want to slice based on the value of **column header** and not based on the **position** of the column.

Please help.

---

**Edit**: 
Based on the answers below, I figured out a way to query the column values. Adding it here for future reference.

```
from datetime import datetime

df[[col for col in df.columns if col not in ("Name", "Location") 
           and col >= datetime(2015,4,1) 
           and col <= datetime(2016,3,1)]]
```

or

```
from datetime import datetime

df.loc[:, [col for col in df.columns if col not in ("Name", "Location") 
       and col >= datetime(2015,4,1) 
       and col <= datetime(2016,3,1)]]
```

The 1st solution is the most elegant.
Conceptually, to column slicing in Pandas works when the intended columns are provided as a list. List comprehenion is used to slice the columns based on column label values. (not the values within the column). In the examples, I have filtered out "Name" and "Location" columns since I am comparing the remaining columns based on datatime value.

Comment: I don't know panda, but you can try doing a filter of the headers that are date-time and if those are comparables, compared it by the value you desire...

Comment: @HVS just updated my answer remembering that you can convert columns into datetime objects and use conditionals as you would normally!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy-fix method would be to replace the Month string with its equivalent number.

```
dct = {'Jan': 1, 'Feb':2 ...}

new = []

for item in df.columns:
    a = item.split('-')

    try: 
       b= '%02d.%02d' %(a[1],a[0])
    except:                                  # if not a datetime i.e. 'name'
       b= str(a[0]) 

    new.append(b)

df.columns=new
```

This should make your dates in the form 15.04,15.05 .. 16.11 etc.

**Alternatively:** You can also Convert your headers into date-times and query them in that way:

```
 from datetime import datetime
 new=[]
 for item in df.columns:
      try:
          new.append( datetime.strptime( item , '%b-%y') )
      except:
          new.append( item )
 df.columns=new

 df.loc[:, df.columns <= datetime(2015, 5, 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks. Your tip lead me to a solution.  df.loc[:, df.columns <= datetime(2015, 5, 1)] did not work because of the non-datetime columns. If you filter it out it works . df.loc[:, [col for col in df.columns if col not in ("Name", "Location") and col >= datetime(2015,4,1) and col <= datetime(2016,3,1)]]

Answer (score 2):

Querying works best to filter observations (rows), based on one or more variables (columns). The way your data is organized doesn't allow for a natural query (You're trying to filter columns as opposed to using them as criteria in the filter). You can read more about [tidying dataframes here](http://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10/v59i10.pdf)

Of course you can come up with a contorted way to do what you want, but I'd strongly suggest you tidy your data like this

```
name | location | date   | value
--------------------------------
John | London   | Apr-15 | 1000
John | London   | May-15 | 800
...
```

Then you can easily query based on the `Date`, and make sure that column is of a date type so you can use e.g.

```
df.query('20150501 < date')
```

Then when you're done and if you have to, you can always bring back the dataframe to its original format if required (If you can, better to avoid it and focus on organizing your data, it pays in the long run)

Comment: thanks for the answer. This is what I am trying to achieve. I want to transform the data with year and month as separate columns. The data format I provided could run for upto 5 years; so 5 * 12 columns. I want to transform this into 13 columns (1 column for year and 12 for months). So I am trying to find ways programmatically.